# Discrepancy between memory usage got through getMemoryMXBean() and jvisualvm?

Tags: java, profiling, mbeans, jvisualvm

When trying to monitor my own program's memory usage through the following code

```
public static String heapMemUsage() 
{
    long used = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed();
    long max = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getMax();
    return ""+used+" of "+max+" ("+ used/(double)max*100.0 + "%)";
}
```

I got a slightly different result than seen through jvisualvm (`17 588 616` in my program vs `18 639 640` in jvisualvm). I know it's not that big of a deal, but it did get me thinking.

Is there any explanation for this fact?

I'd like to use the coded version if possible, but if its results are in some way skewed, being jvisualvm in some way more credible, I'll have to stick with jvisualvm instead.

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if jvisualvm is adding up the heap and non-heap memory usage to get its number. Try adding both of them up in your app to see if you get the closer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VisualVM does use the same approach to get required values, let's check the [MonitoredDataImpl.java](http://java.net/projects/visualvm/sources/svn/content/trunk/visualvm/jvm/src/com/sun/tools/visualvm/jvm/MonitoredDataImpl.java?rev=3190):

```java
MonitoredDataImpl(Jvm vm,JmxSupport jmxSupport,JvmMXBeans jmxModel) {
    //...
    MemoryUsage mem = jmxModel.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage();
    MemoryPoolMXBean permBean = jmxSupport.getPermGenPool();    
    //...
    genCapacity = new long[2];
    genUsed = new long[2];
    genMaxCapacity = new long[2];
    genCapacity[0] = mem.getCommitted();
    genUsed[0] = mem.getUsed();

    genMaxCapacity[0] = mem.getMax();

    if (permBean != null) {
        MemoryUsage perm = permBean.getUsage();
        genCapacity[1] = perm.getCommitted();
        genUsed[1] = perm.getUsed();
        genMaxCapacity[1] = perm.getMax();
    }
  }
```

So it is safe to use your approach anyway. Please post additional info regarding JVM version, etc in order to trace this issue.